# how to collapse panel by clicking on button without clicking on spliter

Tags: c#, winforms

As the picture has been attached below,I have 2 panel from splitcontainercontrol .Panel 1 contains 1 button and panel 2.

I want to ask everybody how to write code for this button(panel1) to collapse panel 2 without changing properties and clicking on spliter when runs app .

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can simply collapse the panel with the following code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
    }
```

If you do not want to change the propery of the panel, then you can hide the panel. Try this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Hide();
    }
```

And you can show the panel with this : `splitContainer1.Panel2.Show();`